# Upgrading from Outlook 2003 to 2007 - only need to download new emails from Exchange Server

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, microsoft-outlook-2003

I am testing Outlook 2003 -> 2007 scenario on Virtual Machine. I'd like to do fresh install because I am not confident everything will go smoothly during in-place upgrade.

Outlook 2007 is installed on VM. VM didn't have Outlook 2003 before. I exported .PST file from 2003 and imported it into Outlook 2007 on VM. I have a bunch of email stored on Exchange Server, it needs to stay there. This email has already been retrieved and is all in imported .PST file.

Then I setup an email account in 2007. Problem is - during Send-Receive it starts to download all email from Exchange Server again even though it is all in .PST file already. Is there a way to disable that?

Comment: MS does not "upgrade" Office.  MS installs 2007 separately from 2003, pulls in the setting from Outlook 2003, and then uninstalls 2003.  Honestly, you should have zero issues.

Comment: OK, this is what I did at the end: via Control Panel selected "Change" for Microsoft office 2003, uninstalled everything except Outlook, then ran 2007 setup. Everything went smoothly and all my email and settings were migrated correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Not that I ever found.   If memory serves: when you export/import the messages with a PST file it changes the modified date on them, and therefore Exchange doesn't see them as the same message.  If you're lucky it will only download them again and give you local dupes.  If you're unlucky it will also UPLOAD them all to your Exchange server, so the dupes end up there as well.

Comment: Correct, it will synchronize ignoring the imported items for download then upload the duplicates to the server.